# How to insert quotes in jq string interpolation in bash

Tags: json, bash, environment-variables, jq

I'm tying to use jq to make to exportable variables in bash. I ran in to an issue with strings that contain spaces. I tried modifying my jq but all I get are invalid character errors. I have tried both single quotes or double quotes but neither have worked for me. What am I missing here?

input:

```
{
   "PD_TOKEN":"Token y_NbAkKc66ryYTWUXYEu",
   "API":"http://cool.api/",
   "HELP_URL":"https://help.com"
}
```

jq:

```
jq -r 'to_entries|map("\(.key)=\(.value|tostring)")' /json
```

current result:

```
PD_TOKEN=Token y_NbAkKc66ryYTWUXYEu
```

wanted result (note the quotation marks):

```
PD_TOKEN="Token y_NbAkKc66ryYTWUXYEu"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`@sh`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Formatstringsandescaping) instead of `tostring` to escape shell-safely:

```
$ jq -r 'to_entries | map("\(.key)=\(.value|@sh)")[]' infile.json
PD_TOKEN='Token y_NbAkKc66ryYTWUXYEu'
API='http://cool.api/'
HELP_URL='https://help.com'
```

Additionally, without `map`:

- Using the array iterator in the first step (h/tip oguz ismail):

  ```sh
  jq -r 'to_entries[] | "\(.key)=\(.value|@sh)"' infile.json
  ```
- Iterate over keys (h/tip ikegami):

  ```sh
  jq -r 'keys[] as $key | "\($key)=\(.[$key]|@sh)"' infile.json
  ```

Comment: Or even shorter, `to_entries[] | "\(.key)=\(.value|@sh)"`.

Comment: Alternatively, `keys[] as $key | "\($key)=\(.[$key]|@sh)"`

Comment: Ooh, nice, let me add those